# Rails don't load google maps javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps

I was trying to load a simple google map in my rails application.

The problem is that the web page show only an empty web page.

Here is my index.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'testmap.js' %>


<body onload="initialize(); ">

<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

This is my testmap.js which is in "public/javascripts":

```
var map;
function initialize() {

    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      center: chicago,
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });
  }
```

The page displayed is completely empty, except for the code loaded from application.html.erb

I hope that you can help me.

Thank you

Comment: In my big ignorance I have forgot to put the style...

  <style> 
    body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
    #map_canvas { height: 320px; width:525px; }
  </style> 

With these lines all work...

Thank you to all

Answer (score 0):

Use something like Firebug for Firefox in order to see if your JS files are loaded or not.

Maybe something like `$(document).ready(function() {}` is necessary (You have to wait that your content is loaded before executing your JS).